# How do you run supervisord in foreground?

Tags: process, supervisord

Is there a way to run supervisord itself in foreground mode? or is there another application that can run/supervise multiple applications and shut them down when itself receives a SIGTERM or equivalent.

Comment: Did you even *attempt* to find this out on your own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [supervisord man page](http://supervisord.org/running.html#supervisord-command-line-options):

```
 -n, --nodaemon     Run supervisord in the foreground.
```

Comment: Not useful. How do you get this to work with the systemd service?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at runit: http://smarden.org/runit/
I am using it for several years now.